# Wicket DropDownChoice read-only

Tags: java, wicket, dropdownchoice

I have a Wicket DropDownChoice and I am trying to avoid using Ajax methods.
After the selection of a value I want the selection to be read-only and the user not be able to change it again.

```
final DropDownChoice<Pet> dropdown = new DropDownChoice<Pet>("dropdown",
                new PropertyModel<Pet>(this, "selected"), list, choiceRenderer) {
// code here
}
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding Ajax? Any solution that is client-side only can be defeated by a browser's development tools

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using Ajax (i.e. using Wicket) to make it read-only then you should do it with custom JavaScript. E.g. using jQuery:

```
jQuery('#petDropdown').change(jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'));
```

i.e. set `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the HTMLSelectElement on the first change event.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to make the dropdown "read-only" without using Ajax or jQuery. I am not happy with that and i will find an alternative solution. Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: Still you can do with attribute modifier

Answer (score 0):

Try to use attribute modifier will do that for you

```
dropdown.add(new AttributeModifier("disabled", "true");
```